# How to display loading image or text in asp:wizard control?

Tags: asp.net, aspwizard

I use an asp:wizard control in my project.when click on next button, load the next step by delay and I want to display loading image "gif" or text such as "Loading ...".
How do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the wizard control post back when you click a step (I can't remember if it does).  If it does, use an UpdatePanel control, and an UpdateProgress control that will appear and show the loading GIF.  Have the wizard postback on every tab load  You can create a loading GIF here: http://ajaxload.info/

If not, the wizard would then be all client-side, and this can be achieved by adding a DIV to the DOM client-side to show your loading panel, by loading the DIV overtop the wizard.